# Windows 10 stuck on welcome screen during AUTO logon

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, microsoft-driver-verifier

I have messed around with my computer trying to update drivers since I got a consistent blue screen with error "System Service Exception". Well the update did not work so I decided to enable the Driver Verifier in windows and followed some instructions (did not make a rollback save and please don't attack this as an answer) and restarted computer. Now whenever windows boots I get to the login screen which automatically logs onto my account and gets stuck on the welcome screen indefinitely (my guess is that Driver Verifier triggered the driver exception).

Is there any way I can cancel the automatic login BEFORE it tries to log into my account? Currently I don't know how else to boot it up in safe mode.

Comment: If Windows fails to boot 3 times it automatically presents the Advanced Startup menu.

Comment: Okay, I am pretty sure I tried more than 3 times yester. But thanks! Will take a look at that after work regardless

Comment: A little late, but it worked. I couldn't fix the computer but I did get to the advanced startup after 3 consecutive restarts.